# Has any one used Contentful with Unity3D as the front end?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, contentful, contentful-management

For one of our HoloLens projects, we need to connect and get layout information from Contentful. Has anyone used the Contentful .NET SDK with Unity3D so far?

Comment: I am the maintainer of the Contentful .NET SDK. I love the idea of bringing Contentful into HoloLens, if you wanna chat more about it reach out to me. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Contentful .NET SDK targets NetStandard 1.4 which Unity does not yet support. However as soon as NetStandard 2.0 is released we will move the SDK to target this instead. Unity will be targeting NetStandard 2.0 "soon" according to this thread: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/why-not-netstandard.458636/

There are no exact dates yet for the release of NetStandard 2.0 nor for when Unity will start supporting it. I'll update this answer as things move along.

**Update 2017-08-15**
The Contentful .NET SDK now targets NetStandard 2.0 which was just released. No date yet for when Unity will support it, but it's coming.

Comment: Thanks Robban, appreciated